# React Native - Element Type Is invalid ( Simple Page View)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have problem with React Navigator, I am really new at react native and many solution seems far fetch from my main problem. I Already follow as close as the documentation says. any how i still get this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> number.
>
> Check the render method of `Splash`.

This is my App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Splash from './pages/Splash';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Quick Import to Splash.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { ILLogo } from '../assets'

const Splash = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <ILLogo />
            <Text style={styles.title}>Hooray!!!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Splash;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
        backgroundColor: '#2BA3DC',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#fff',
        marginTop: 20
    }
});
```

I tried to get the export of splash with many way and importing it to, Please Help me

Comment: How’s ILLogo exported?

Comment: @SaachiTech `import ILLogo from './Logo.svg';` from Illustration folder index,js and `export * from './illustration';` from assets folder

Comment: Please add that in your question